# Get width of UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the problem i can't get width of `<ul>`.

html file:

```
<ul>
    <li>image goes here</li>
    <li>image goes here</li>
    <li>image goes here</li>
</ul>
```

css file:

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

 li {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

here is example of Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $width = $('ul').width();
    console.log('width: ' + $width); 
});
```

it returns 0 how to get ul width ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CSS** function `css`with `wdith` as attribute:

```
$('ul').css("width");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $width = $('ul').css("width");
  console.log('width: ' + $width);
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>image goes here</li>
  <li>image goes here</li>
  <li>image goes here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i forgot `display: inline-block` to li.

Comment: @BatgerelEnkhbat my solution is working too ^^ but i'm happy that you've find what you missed good luck